# When using the default British keyboard layout, some apps won't let me input #

Tags: keyboard

For some reason, on my iMac, `[alt]+3` will enter the `#` symbol as it's supposed to in some applications (e.g. Xcode), while in others (e.g. Safari, Terminal...) it just makes a little error 'beep'.

It's not a major problem, since I can use a different key layout and the problem is resolved, but it's always bugged me that I couldn't determine the source of this behaviour. It has persisted through Mountain Lion, Mavericks, Yosemite.

I also have a Macbook Pro with mostly similar configuration and things installed AFAIK, but it doesn't have this problem.

Comment: I do not have this problem on my MBP as well. In Terminal, you could perhaps go to Preferences > Encoding and enable UTF-8 etc. You can do the same in Safari > Preferences > Advanced > Default Encoding

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; doesn't seem to make a difference in Safari, Terminal already had UTF-8 along with lots of others (the defaults)... I haven't tried unchecking others. The thing is, they're willing to accept the character, but not via the standard `alt+3` with the standard keyboard layout.

Comment: Also make sure that you don't have alt-3 as some sort of shortcut. You can check in **System Prefs** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts**

Comment: A workaround would be to chnage the keyboard setting to Australian see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977069/emacs-question-hash-key/3977314#3977314

Comment: Checking keyboard shortcuts was another good suggestion, but no dice (I think I'd already looked there a while ago). I am now using a custom keyboard map which is identical to standard British but with § mapped to #, so it's working ok, just would still like to understand why this happened.